# How to download a video from vidyard that I have access for

Tags: video, download, http-live-streaming, m3u8

It looks like all of the URLs related to m3u8 or ts files are showing up 403 forbidden on direct access in the address bar, using blob: or without.

When I click play on the video, I can see on the network activity tab that they are downloaded, but they look like very small sizes.

I was able to bookmark the URL which looks like this => https://play.vidyard.com/somestring

What steps and processes or HLS plugin I can use to download these videos?

I thought using screen recording also, but this would be last resort, in case there is no available easier to use option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with youtube-dl and ffmpeg:
youtube-dl "https://cdn.vidyard.com/media/hls/xxxxxxxxx-Q/,full_hd,hd,480p,sd,.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8?token" --add-header "Referer: [https://play.vidyard.com/"](https://play.vidyard.com/%22) --ffmpeg-location c:\youtube-dl\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe